# Should this old question be closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Website to know about books something similar to IMDB for movies?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5773/website-to-know-about-books-something-similar-to-imdb-for-movies) is an old question.  It has a couple issues: as noted in a comment (from 2012) it's a list question, but, perhaps more significantly, it seems to be a question about *reading*, not about *writing*.  I was going to mod-close it but then I noticed its age. Why hasn't this been closed already?  Is there a reason it should be open?

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the "list question" aspect and the reading-specific nature of the question as originally posted, questions about readers' perceptions of books do (I think) have a place at Writers SE, mainly for marketing-related aspects (what is popular, what expectations readers have, etc.). That is, I think a valid question for Writers *might* be extractable from the question (though such an edit would do so much violence to the question that I suspect a different question might be better — aside from the benefit of closing a clearly off-topic question).

A writer might even use ratings and reviews to guide certain writing decisions (i.e., not just post-production marketing decisions).

I suspect that answers to such a question would also point out that better methods are available for making such decisions.

---

Yes, I find some pleasure in thinking of ways that a question can be rescued. In this case, I think any rescue would so violate the original poster's intent that it would be inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this question has anything to do with writing. Please close.

(List questions should be allowed, in my opinion.)

Comment: The problem is not questions that generate lists, but questions that generate *open* lists where a definitive answer is not possible or would be too long for a Stack Exchange answer. Even "good" list questions tend to generate add-on answers. The SE format seems weak at encouraging wiki-like collaboration to form one good answer, but valid list questions amplify this weakness by encouraging one or two item partial answers (and late summary answers seem not to be voted to the top even if provided).